# Aspect Oriented programming for Log4j automatic implementing method

Tags: aop

Using the AspectJ compiler how to  add a logging code after and before the execution of all methods in particular class
where to write the below code and how to run

```
aspect AspectExample {
    before() : execution(* Point.*(..)) {
        logger.entering(thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getName(), thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringType() );
    } after() : execution(* Point.*(..)) {
        logger.exiting(thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getName() , thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringType() );
    }
}
```

Comment: aspect AspectExample {
    before() : execution(* Point.*(..))
    {
         logger.entering(thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getName(), thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringType()   );

    }

    after() : execution(* Point.*(..))
    {
         logger.exiting(thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getName() , thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringType()  );

    }
}

Comment: where to write this code and how the run the above code

Comment: Please edit your question to add details instead of commenting.